# Pattern for a one-time action

Tags: design-patterns

How to display an action that can only be enabled once?

I originally considered a checkbox, but the user wouldn't be able to uncheck it once selected.
Another option I think might work would be to display an 'Enable' button with descriptive text, and disable it once enabled.

Comment: Can you share any more details about this, such as the workflow? Would you be able to give an example of this action, or explain why it can only be enabled once?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a one-time action you only really want the "control" to be there so the user can perform the action. Once the action is committed, it doesn't make any sense for the control to still be visible at all. Instead, just show some descriptive text for the user so they know that the action has been performed.

You will have to excuse my generic examples as your question doesn't have enough information for me to offer more specific text. However, the concept is to make it clear to the user that the action cannot be reverted, and only show the button when the action is available. Once committed, the button should no longer be visible and is replaced by a message that indicates the action has been applied.

Something like this:

[image]

---

With something like this it is important that the user is required to confirm the action they are performing. Typically this is often done with a pop-up dialog with a "confirm"/"cancel" choice. However, an alternative to a pop-up could be to have combination of checkbox and button when performing the action.

For example:

[image]

If the action is deemed *really* important, you might want to still add the pop-up confirmation as a further step to this checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal control for an action: a button — but present a confirmation dialog when the user clicks it, providing a notice of the consequence of their action and its permanence, prompting them to acknowledge and confirm or cancel.

[image: button]

*button*

[image: confirmation dialog]

*after clicking button*